# View window shifts to right when scrolling to the bottom

Tags: line-numbers, fringe-mode

I recently starting using vanilla emacs, specifically for org mode. I noticed something odd happening when I try to display line numbers in my files. Near the top of the file, the line numbers are a certain distance away from the left of the entire frame:

[image: distance from numbers and left frame border near top of file]

However, when I scroll to the bottom of the document, everything seems to shift to the right slightly.

[image: distance from numbers and left frame border near bottom of file]

Notice how the numbers are farther away from the left border of the frame, and everything has shifted slightly to the right. Why is this happening? Does anyone know how I can prevent things from shifting to the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the value of the option `display-line-numbers-width` is `nil`, in which case Emacs will calculate the width of the line numbers.
IOW, if the width of the line numbers is about to increase, Emacs will increase the width of the line number column, because the line numbers are right-aligned.

I guess you will also ask why not use the space on the left side of the line number column directly; actually, that space is not for the line numbers, it has other uses (see the manual).
If you feel that this blank space is a waste, you can use

```
(set-fringe-mode '(0 . nil))  ; which is also my choice.
```

to remove it.

Comment: +1 on the answer, although I disagree about the fringe: I find it useful. OTOH, I find `display-line-numbers-mode` line numbers a waste of space: most of the time I do not need them and when I think I *do* need them, there are almost always better ways to do what I need (I do use `line-number-mode` though).

Comment: @NickD: "*I find `display-line-numbers-mode` line numbers a waste of space*" -- Sometimes it is. So displaying the current line number in the mode line is also a good choice.